# Why a covered count query is slow?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm running a mongodb v3.2.12 sharded cluster. Shard key is `_id` which is a md5 hash.
The problem is, that a covered count query takes much time.

The used index is about 5 GB on each mongodb node. The total size of all indexes is 32 GB and fits perfectly in RAM since each node has 128 GB RAM.

The query is: `db.offer.count({ "shopId": 275419, "missingSince": null})`

The used index has been created as: `db.offer.createIndex({shopId:1, missingSince:1, merchantId:1, _id:1}, {background:true})`

As you can see, the index is **not sparse**, so even null values are present in the index.

Running `db.currentOp()` while the query is running shows that the query is using the right index, However, it is running for over 2814 seconds already:

```
    {
        "desc" : "conn56062",
        "threadId" : "140131556767488",
        "connectionId" : 56062,
        "client_s" : "x.x.x.x:39177",
        "active" : true,
        "opid" : "offerStoreIT02:1075309911",
        "secs_running" : 2814,
        "microsecs_running" : NumberLong("2814791918"),
        "op" : "command",
        "ns" : "offerStore.offer",
        "query" : {
                "query" : {
                        "count" : "offer",
                        "query" : {
                                "missingSince" : null,
                                "shopId" : 275419
                        }
                },
                "$readPreference" : {
                        "mode" : "primaryPreferred"
                }
        },
        "planSummary" : "IXSCAN { shopId: 1.0, missingSince: 1.0, merchantId: 1.0, _id: 1.0 }",
        "numYields" : 249244,
        "locks" : {
                "Global" : "r",
                "Database" : "r",
                "Collection" : "r"
        },
        "waitingForLock" : false,
        "lockStats" : {
                "Global" : {
                        "acquireCount" : {
                                "r" : NumberLong(498490)
                        }
                },
                "Database" : {
                        "acquireCount" : {
                                "r" : NumberLong(249245)
                        }
                },
                "Collection" : {
                        "acquireCount" : {
                                "r" : NumberLong(249245)
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Iterating a 5 GB in-memory index never takes so much time. While the query is running, each mongodb primary is reading constantly 75-100 MB/sec from disk. When the query is not running, only 5-10 MB/sec are read from disk, so my assumption is that mongodb fetches the documents from SSD into memory in order to count them.

But why is it so? The query should be covered by the index since all fields, including the shardkey, is present in the index, which should be sufficient to cover the query according to mongodb documentation:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/#covered-queries

**Follow-up:**

I broke down the problem to a minimalistic, unsharded setup. I inserted the following types of documents:

- a) 3 documents without both fields `shopId` and `missingSince`
- b) 5 documents with field `shopId:1` without field `missingSince`
- c) 7 documents with field `shopId:1` and `missingSince:null`
- d) 13 documents with field `shopId:1` and `missingSince:ISODate("2017-05-22T07:52:40.831Z")`

I created the index `{shopId:1, missingSince:1}`.
The execution plan of the query `count({"shopId":1, "missingSince":null})` indicated `"totalDocsExamined" : 12` which means that 12 documents had to be fetched. These must be the 5 documents of b) plus the 7 documents of c). All these 12 documents should be in the index with `shopId:1, missingSince:null`, thus satisfying the query.

**But why does mongodb still need to fetch and examine these 12 documents?**

Here is my test collection:

```
rs1:PRIMARY> db.offer.find()
{ "_id" : 1, "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 2, "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 3, "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 4, "shopId" : 1, "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 5, "shopId" : 1, "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 6, "shopId" : 1, "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 7, "shopId" : 1, "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 8, "shopId" : 1, "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 9, "shopId" : 1, "missingSince" : null, "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 10, "shopId" : 1, "missingSince" : null, "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 11, "shopId" : 1, "missingSince" : null, "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 12, "shopId" : 1, "missingSince" : null, "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 13, "shopId" : 1, "missingSince" : null, "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 14, "shopId" : 1, "missingSince" : null, "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 15, "shopId" : 1, "missingSince" : null, "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 16, "shopId" : 1, "missingSince" : ISODate("2017-05-22T07:52:40.831Z"), "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 17, "shopId" : 1, "missingSince" : ISODate("2017-05-22T07:52:40.831Z"), "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 18, "shopId" : 1, "missingSince" : ISODate("2017-05-22T07:52:40.831Z"), "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 19, "shopId" : 1, "missingSince" : ISODate("2017-05-22T07:52:40.831Z"), "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 20, "shopId" : 1, "missingSince" : ISODate("2017-05-22T07:52:40.831Z"), "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 21, "shopId" : 1, "missingSince" : ISODate("2017-05-22T07:52:40.831Z"), "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 22, "shopId" : 1, "missingSince" : ISODate("2017-05-22T07:52:40.831Z"), "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 23, "shopId" : 1, "missingSince" : ISODate("2017-05-22T07:52:40.831Z"), "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 24, "shopId" : 1, "missingSince" : ISODate("2017-05-22T07:52:40.831Z"), "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 25, "shopId" : 1, "missingSince" : ISODate("2017-05-22T07:52:40.831Z"), "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 26, "shopId" : 1, "missingSince" : ISODate("2017-05-22T07:52:40.831Z"), "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 27, "shopId" : 1, "missingSince" : ISODate("2017-05-22T07:52:40.831Z"), "v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 28, "shopId" : 1, "missingSince" : ISODate("2017-05-22T07:52:40.831Z"), "v" : 1 }
```

Here is the output of explain():

```
rs1:PRIMARY> db.offer.explain(true).count({"shopId":1, "missingSince":null})
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "test.offer",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$and" : [
                {
                    "missingSince" : {
                        "$eq" : null
                    }
                },
                {
                    "shopId" : {
                        "$eq" : 1
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "COUNT",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "missingSince" : {
                        "$eq" : null
                    }
                },
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "shopId" : 1,
                        "missingSince" : 1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "shopId_1_missingSince_1",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 1,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "shopId" : [
                            "[1.0, 1.0]"
                        ],
                        "missingSince" : [
                            "[null, null]"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
    },
    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 0,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 0,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 12,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 12,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "COUNT",
            "nReturned" : 0,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
            "works" : 13,
            "advanced" : 0,
            "needTime" : 12,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 0,
            "restoreState" : 0,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "nCounted" : 12,
            "nSkipped" : 0,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "missingSince" : {
                        "$eq" : null
                    }
                },
                "nReturned" : 12,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                "works" : 13,
                "advanced" : 12,
                "needTime" : 0,
                "needYield" : 0,
                "saveState" : 0,
                "restoreState" : 0,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "docsExamined" : 12,
                "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "nReturned" : 12,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                    "works" : 13,
                    "advanced" : 12,
                    "needTime" : 0,
                    "needYield" : 0,
                    "saveState" : 0,
                    "restoreState" : 0,
                    "isEOF" : 1,
                    "invalidates" : 0,
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "shopId" : 1,
                        "missingSince" : 1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "shopId_1_missingSince_1",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 1,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "shopId" : [
                            "[1.0, 1.0]"
                        ],
                        "missingSince" : [
                            "[null, null]"
                        ]
                    },
                    "keysExamined" : 12,
                    "dupsTested" : 0,
                    "dupsDropped" : 0,
                    "seenInvalidated" : 0
                }
            }
        },
        "allPlansExecution" : [ ]
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "Kays MacBook Pro",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "3.2.6",
        "gitVersion" : "05552b562c7a0b3143a729aaa0838e558dc49b25"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: how many docs are in offer collection? Does the query without count run faster as compared to when the count is included?

Comment: Why is the `_id` field in this index? That's basically redundant since there already is an index on the `_id` field. I'm thinking your going to get a big boost by simply dropping this index and using one without the included `_id` field. For test purposes, create an index just for the fields you want as criteria and use `.hint()` to force selection of that index.

Comment: FYI. The general concept of "covered queries" is that all the data required is contained within the selected index. 9 times out of 10  the big killer here is wanting to retrieve more data that is contained in the index fields used. but if you are just doing `.count()`, then this basically negates the effect of document retrieval. Since nothing is actually retrieved.

Comment: @Astro, there are 250 million documents in the collection. Find is as slow as count.

Comment: can you try index mentioned below?

Comment: @Neil Lunn, the _id field has been added to the index in order to meet the requirements for covered queries in sharded environments (see the link that i've posted above already: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/#covered-queries ).
Btw. we firstly have been using an index without _id and run into exactly the same problems. Then we read in the above mentioned documentation that the shardkey needs to be present in the index to cover the query. We've done this by adding a new index with the _id field at its end but nevertheless the query does not seem to be covered.

Comment: Can you add the output of `.explain()`?  Also, the documentation at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/count/ mentions that `count()` may not be accurate on sharded clusters. I don't know if that matters to you, but thought I would bring it up in case you were not aware.

Comment: @Jeff, we have none or only very little chunk migrations thanks to our md5 shardkey and presplitting. Also we check regulary orphans and delete them if found, which never happend so far. The loss of count accuracy after a unexpected shutdown only applies to count operations that do not include a query document, so this does not apply to us.
I'm hesitating to run the query again with `explain` to have the execution plan because the query puts much stress on the whole database system and slows it significantly down. 
I might have an idea why is it so but need to confirm. I'll report back.

Comment: @Kay, I am guessing that Mongo uses a negation to search for null under the hood.  Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39812096/compound-mongo-index-optimization-for-query-with-null-false-and-true, which has some similar problem.  It also references the MongoDB Best Practices white paper at https://webassets.mongodb.com/_com_assets/collateral/MongoDB-Performance-Best-Practices.pdf?_ga=1.211821597.888499800.1464953152.  Neither directly answer the question, but add a little bit of insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody could find a valid reason for this issue, I opened yesterday a mongodb bug report: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-29326

Mongodb engineers confirmed that's a bug. Unfortunately it's not mentioned in mongodb's documentation which would have saved us many hours tracing down the issue and deploy another schema design from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Try this index:

If your existing index `db.offer.createIndex({shopId:1, missingSince:1, merchantId:1, _id:1}, {background:true})` 
is used for another purpose, try creating following index on offer collection:

```
db.offer.createIndex({missingSince:1,shopId:1}, {background:true})
```

This will optimize the query itself and thus count.

Comment: This index will be far less effective because the first field "missingSince" is not as selective as the second field "shopId". Querying `missingSince:null`with such an index would lead to a nearly full collection scan.